# Is it possible to run Puma as a webserver all by itself?

Tags: ruby, puma

I followed [the instruction](https://github.com/puma/puma) to do

```
gem install puma
puma
```

but it can't start a webserver, and is supposed to look for `config.ru`.  Must Puma be run with Rack and Rails?  Can Puma be run as a standalone webserver?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to run Puma as a webserver without rack?

**No.**

Puma like Thin and Unicorn is a Rack server. Rack is just really a basic common gateway interface and I can't really see why you would want to build any sort of web application in Ruby without using Rack unless you want to [build a server from scratch out of curiosity](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCPSocket.html).

Building a [basic hello world app with rack](https://gist.github.com/markbates/4240848) is trivial:

```
# config.ru
run ->(env) { [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, ["Hello World!"]] }
```

> Must Puma be run with Rack and Rails?

Rails is not a requirement for any Rack server that I know of.

Comment: with WEBrick we can run it as a standalone server using `ruby -run -e httpd . -p 8080` I guess Puma or Unicorn just can't

Comment: Yeah you're probably right on that one. It's not like it's a really useful feature though.

Comment: I am just experimenting with Docker, so I am just trying out how it'd be like running Ruby and a webserver with it instead of Nginx or Apache

Comment: Apache and nginx will always win at serving up static files but what you're doing is serving up some sort of application it makes huge sense to have some sort of interface so that its plug and play and rack is also highly optimized so I think it's hard to actually write something faster without doing it all in C.

Comment: yeah it is just for experimentation rather than for speed

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Sort of.

You do not have to have the rack gem installed, if that's what you are wondering. But perhaps that's because Puma contains it's own rack builder/handler.

https://medium.com/@lfv89/rackless-ruby-servers-why-not-a9f8430067dd

Here's the actual code snippet:

/puma-5.1.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:328

```
  begin
    require 'rack'
    require 'rack/builder'
  rescue LoadError
    # ok, use builtin version
    return Puma::Rack::Builder
  else
    return ::Rack::Builder
  end
```